# Identifying recent activity on question and answers page

Tags: feature-request

If one has on display a specific page, usually a question and answers, is there a method to highlight or find activity for the current day or recent period?

Comment: I would think this can be done only to a very limited extent. You can sort the answers by activity at least. But I think that does not account for comments.